# Proton jumbuck loss of power/shaking

Tags: engine

I was driving to work this smorning when my car started shaking and losing power no matter how much I put my foot down after about 2km of driving it started working fine again but the engine has a ticking noise occasionally when low in revs, it also had a weird smell to it, sorry I can't define the smell, does anyone have any suggestions it's a proton jumbuck 2003 model

Answer (score 1):

The screeching belts from time to time would be signicant. If you have a failing water pump, alternator, power steering pump, belt tensioner or AirCon unit they can act as a brake on the engine and give the symptoms you describe. Recent work in this area would mean a very close examination of any components affected by the belt change. The smell could be coming from a belt skidding as it tried to turn a partial seizing component.

Answer (score 0):

How many miles are on the Engine? Any OBD codes?
Check for vacuum and exhaust leaks. If non appear then check the oil level. After that if the oil looks good, run the car, let the engine warm up and then remove the fuel filler cap or dipstick, look for smoke. If there is smoke the engine is burning up oil. This could be a problem you are having.

If all looks good there, it may be a burnt valve. That is the nuclear option. If it is low mileage this probably wont occur.

Ticking is usually caused by Lifters in the engine when the oil level is low.

Comment: 144xxx oil is all good will check for leaks tomorrow before work ill look at the valves as well and will get back to u thanks heaps mate

Comment: It does seen to be getting a lot of air and the fan belts/ trimming belts screech at times but there brand new and tightened properly what could be going on there?